# Is it a good idea to distribute records of one table into several multiple tables having similar table structure

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table with records 62 Million.

```
Table structure: 52 columns
Storage engine: InnoDB
Collation: utf8_general_ci



SELECT - Maximum number of operations performed

INSERT - Always in bulk but it doesn't happen always.

UPDATE - Very less number of operations but sometime much and sometime not at all
```

Since we are fetching in real time almost always. Is it a good idea to distribute records from this one big table in some logic into multiple similar tables in order to select record pretty much faster?

**MYSQL Version: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.33-MariaDB**

Comment: define "pretty much faster". faster than what? what's wrong with your database right now?

Comment: At the moment our web application is very slow sometime. For a normal webhook (By external API) it takes 30 sec to respond where it should take less than 1 sec.

Comment: Unless you're planning to put those smaller tables on a different server or the query can be split to ignore certain tables (eg, older data that normally won't be referenced) I can't see why multiple tables can yield faster query.

Comment: define "sometime". define "very slow". define "normal webhook"  -  what does it do, what queries does it run, which concrete part is slow? Did you ever have an idea to narrow down the problem to a certain query? How do you looking for the solution for the problem which is not even defined?

Comment: Also, the speed of the queries is influenced by a lot of things. Have you looked at indexes and query design before trying to come up with such optimisation techniques?

Comment: @Martheen How it would make a difference to put smaller tables on a different but not on the same database ?

I agree about the option of older data. But all those data can be used in any point of time regardless of how old the data is.

Comment: @YourCommonSense You are right. We are narrowing down the problems in order to know which part needs optimisation

Comment: If they're put on different servers (not just database, but actual different hardware), you have all the extra IO, CPU and RAM to deal with the subquery. But if they're running on the same hardware, you're not going to gain any speedup, the query should've already exhaust at least one bottleneck

Comment: @Shadow Yes, indexes have been implemented. 

Sorry I don't understand when you say "query design" ?

Comment: @Martheen The server's hardware is very strong. 128GB RAM, intel xeon etc. Do you think still it is good to put on different server?

Comment: What is the resource usage during the query run? If it turns out it already exhausts all cores or hobbled by IO speed, then you'd need a different server.

Comment: @user_387909 query design is how you write your query. Two queries may have the same output, but their execution plan and therefore their speed may be vastly different.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost guaranteed to be slower by that technique.

Provide `CREATE TABLE` and the important queries.

Often a `SELECT` can be sped up by a composite index and/or a reformulation.

62M rows is above average, but not a scary size.

"INSERT - Always in bulk" -- Let's see your technique; there may be a way to speed it up further.

"Archiving" old data -- Actually removing the data may help some.  Keeping it around, but using suitable indexes is usually fine.  *We need to see your queries and schema*.

"Sharding" is putting parts of the data in separate servers.  This is handy when you have exhausted the write capacity of a single machine.

"Replication" (Primary + Replica) allows shifting *reads* to another server, thereby spreading the load.  With this technique, you system can handle a virtually unlimited number of `SELECTs`.

"Yes, indexes have been implemented" -- That may mean that you have one index per column.  This is almost always *not* optimal.

"128GB RAM" -- If the entire dataset is much smaller than that, then most of the RAM is going unused.

"Query design" -- I had one example of a CPU that was pegged at 100%.  After making the following change, the CPU dropped to 1%:

```
SELECT ... WHERE DATE(dt) = CURDATE();
```

-->

```
SELECT ... WHERE dt >= CURDATE();
```